# Either remove or automatically enter pem passphrase for haproxy ssl; Chrome still warns about CA not signed

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, haproxy, keytool

I recently received a signed certificate to use with haproxy SSL termination.  In order for haproxy to use this, I needed to convert the jks file to a pem file.  First, I converted the cer files I received into crt, as I had a previous error where haproxy was not able to find the crt files in the pem file.  Do this for all certs:

```
$ openssl x509 -inform PEM -in <CER file here> -out <CRT output file>
```

I then import the root, intermediate, and service certs to the keystore, which already has the private key:

```
keytool -importcert -file $CERT -alias $ALIAS -keystore test.jdk
```

I then convert the jsk file to a p12 file, followed by converting that to a pem file:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test.jks -destkeystore test.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
Enter destination keystore password:
Re-enter new password:


$ openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -out test.pem
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

This generates a pem file with the following format:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName:
    localKeyID: 
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName:
subject=
issuer=
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName:
subject=
issuer=
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: 
subject=
issuer=
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName:
    localKeyID:
subject=
issuer=
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Obviously, there is a lot of information missing from this, as I do not want to share that online;  however, the structure is pretty much identical.

When I link this to haproxy:

```
frontend https
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4000 ssl crt /home/user/config/cert/test.pem
```

And I run it with `haproxy -d -f haproxy.cfg`, I'm asked to enter the PEM pass phrase.  I need to be able to start haproxy automatically on server start up, so I can't enter this every time I want to run it.  Is there any way to remove the pass phrase, or generate a pem file without one?  Or can I supply via a script?  The script I use to start haproxy on server start up is just the command you see above, with nohup to redirect the output.

Also, when I go to one of the services fronted by haproxy, Chrome still warns me that the CA is not trusted, like when I used a self signed certificate.  Is there anything else I need to do beyond what I have above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to copy the password protected key to a not password protected key.

```
openssl rsa -in test.pem -out test-password-less.key
```

To provide the PEM now to HAProxy will you also need the certificate. 
cat both Files to **one** PEM File for haproxy.

```
cat $CERT test-password-less.key > haproxy-test.pem
```

Comment: Or create the combined file with already unencrypted key: `openssl pkcs12 -in p12file -nodes -out pemfile`

Answer (score 0):

or instead remove pem passphrase on e.g an Amazon EC2 Fedora Linux instance:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -p -f EC2.pem
```